# Change class name of font-awesome when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the problem

This is my `html` code

```
        <div id="bookmark">
            <i class="far fa-bookmark"></i>
        </div>
```

I want to change `.far` to `.fas` and vice versa in `loop` when clicked.

This is my updated javascript

```
function changeClass(elem) {
    var i = elem.childNodes[1];
    var c = i.classList;
    console.log(i)
    console.log(c)

    // Change class
    if (c.contains("far")) {
        i.classList.remove("far");
        i.classList.add("fas");
    } else {
        i.classList.remove("fas");
        i.classList.add("far");
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the console output in the browser when I click on the bookmark icon

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZn60.png)

When I pass the index value in the `var c` respectively, on `i.classList[0]` I get `svg-inline--fa` but I get `undefined` value in `i.classList[3]` instead of `far`. SO WHAT SHOULD I DO?

Comment: please share a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: it's not a punishment. SO is not for getting answers to your homework. you need to show what you have tried and where you are facing an issue

Comment: For trying, I should know where to start, but I don't know

Comment: There are few steps in the learning path. 1. Learn what is div, id and class; 2. Learn how to access html tags with JS; 3. Learn how to change html on events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for (Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hwv0oacL/8/)

> HTML

```
<div id="bookmark" onclick="changeClass(this)">
    <i class="far fa-bookmark"></i>
</div>
```

> Javascript

```
changeClass(elem) {
    var i = elem.childNodes[0].classList;
    
    // Change class far to fas
    if (i.includes("far")) {
        i.classList.remove("far");
        i.classList.add("fas");
    }

    // Get back to original state
    if (i.includes("fas")) {
        i.classList.remove("fas");
        i.classList.add("far");
    }
}
```

**-------------------Updated--------------------------**

Replace the above javascript with the one below. It will also work in loop like you want because we are getting element by `this` keyword.

> JavaScript

```
function changeClass(elem) {
    var i = elem.childNodes[1];
    var c = i.classList;

    // Change class
    if (c.contains("far")) {
        i.classList.remove("far");
        i.classList.add("fas");
    } else {
        i.classList.remove("fas");
        i.classList.add("far");
    }
}
```

Comment: @MeetGondaliya Updated my code, check now.

Comment: still same status

Comment: @MeetGondaliya Bro I don't know how you are doing it or maybe I didn't explain it well so I made a fiddle for you to check out: https://jsfiddle.net/hwv0oacL/8/

Comment: Bro sorry for the disagreement. Your code works fine in JSFIDDLE, even the hovering effect works in my system but the bookmark doesn't change to solid. I think `z-index` will do it, but still, if anything you can think to debug it, please let me know.

Comment: I have edited the Question and uploaded a screenshot of the console

Comment: Why there is "<svg>" tag in your screenshot while in your question you add "<i>" tag. Which one you want, the one with "<svg>" or the one with "<i>"

Comment: Bro I have same code as your jsfiddle code but in console it shows `svg` instead of `li`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below with jQuery:

```
$("#bookmark").find("i").removeClass("far");
$("#bookmark").find("i").addClass("fas");
```

Comment: This is working but I cant loop it on every click

Comment: Can you share the code which you call these removeClass-addClass codes?

Comment: I have edited what I had done in the script tag

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want this to be done for single element and not for all the elements that are using .far class

add an id to the  tag like id="i1" then you can add an event listener on that element. listening to the click event and once captured - toggle the class.

add the following just before the end of the body tag i.e. before `</body>`

```
<script>
document.getElementById('i1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('far');
    e.target.classList.toggle('fas');
})
</script>
```

Comment: Yes its working, but how can I loop it on every click?

Comment: what do you mean by looping? it should work on every click, ideally.

Comment: looping means, when on click it changes from `far` to `fas`, after next click it should change from `fas` to `far`, alternatively.

Comment: yeah it should work like that, as we have used toggle method.

Comment: from your code it comes back to its original state only when I refresh it, but does not happen on click

Comment: as per the code you have written in the main question, its wrong... you are adding event listeners unnecessarily!

Comment: you only need to add single event listener that will toggle the class in the class list when clicked, you are mixing up multiple solutions I guess. when you use toggle it will remove the class if already present and will add otherwise. so no need to check the conditions if present or not!

Comment: My mistake that I added extra event listeners and thank you for your guidance but still I can't toggle with your code

Comment: still code is incorrect! you are using parent tag's id. read the solution again

Comment: adding `id` to `i` tag doesn't event change the class, so I tried to add it to parent tag